# JPanel not appearing when added to parent JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm dumbfounded here. I have a `JPanel` (defBoardPanel) that I'm adding to a parent `JPanel` (GamePanel) as follows:

```
  public GamePanel(SetupBoard sb) {
     this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  //  this.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    JPanel defBoardPanel = new JPanel();
    defBoardPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

    for (int r = 0; r < sb.boardSize; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c <  sb.boardSize; c++){
            Cell c = new Cell(r, c);       
            c.label.setOpaque(true);
            if (sb.getCell(r, c).status == sb.getCell(r,c).status.occupied){
                c.label.setBackground(Color.black);
                System.out.println("LABEL IS OCCUPIED");
            }
            else {
                c.label.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            defBoardPanel.add(c.label);
        }
    }

    defBoardPanel.revalidate();
    defBoardPanel.setVisible(true);
    this.add(defBoardPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.revalidate();
    this.setVisible(true);
```

This panel is to be added to a JFrame (MainFrame), which is shown below. When the application is launched, the JFrame displays a different type of Panel (SetupBoard), with which the user sets up their game board. When they click "accept", the StartGame() method of the MainFrame is called, which should show the JPanels above.

```
public MainFrame() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setSize(500, 500);

    SetupBoard sb = new SetupBoard(10, this);
    this.setContentPane(sb);

 }

    void startGame(SetupBoard sb){
        GamePanel gp = new GamePanel(sb);
        this.setContentPane(gp);
        this.revalidate();

}
```

My issue is that the child panel (defBoardPanel) is not displaying. The GamePanel itself displays (which I've verified using the `setBackground(Color.yellow)` method you see commented out), but not the panel I've added onto it.

What stupid mistake am I overlooking here?

EDIT: startGame() is being called from within the SetupBoard class:

```
void startGame(){
    mf.startGame(this);
}
```

where mf is a reference to the MainFrame that created the SetupBoard instance. The fact that the GamePanel displays at all confirms that this is being called correctly.

Comment: Do you actually call `startGame`? For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Reimeus yes, please see edit. Also, I tried to create an SSCCE, but I couldn't replicate the behavior.

Comment: You don't appear to have put any components inside defBoardPanel, nor have you given it a specific size. It's possible that defBoardPanel has zero size, so you're not seeing it. Try setting the size of the panel, and then call pack() on your JFrame object to reposition everything based on panel and component sizes.

Comment: @Arkanon - I had initially not posted where I added components to the defBoardPanel, but have posted that now. Also, I've tried setting the size of the panel but with no result.

Comment: Have you called the pack() method of the JFrame object?

Comment: @Arkanon - yes I have...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see your problem.  I do know that, when I'm doing this sort of thing, I call JFrame.pack() after I'm done setting things up, and I only ever call revalidate() when I'm doing something unusual.  If your board is supposed to look like a chessboard, I do suggest looking into a grid layout, but that doesn't address your question.

Comment: wait, you add a bunch of labels to your defboard panel, but do the labels have anything in/on them at all?  If they're all 0 size, then the panel will be 0 size, and won't show up on a borderLayout.CENTER nohow.

Comment: They're not. They're given a size, color, and made opaque in the constructor of the Cell class. Also, the defBoardPanel() is a GridLayout, although I realize that code isn't in my post. Thanks for the suggestion, though :)

Comment: i was concerned that when you did this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); and this had a layout you needed to remove it first but i'm told taht doesn't matter so i'm going to watch.

Comment: Btw, your calls to `revalidate()` and `setVisible(true)` in your `GamePanel` constructor are needless because `GamePanel` has no parent yet

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - I know, they were added as desperate attempts to figure out the problem here..

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work ok if I trim the code I don't have. Most likely the issue is coming from what you are not showing us. Therefore, producing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would greatly benefit you. Meanwhile, you can always take advantage (to find the differences with your code) of the following one, which is highly originated from yours (I filled some gaps as I could):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int COLS = 10;
    private static final int ROWS = 10;

    public GamePanel() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // this.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        JPanel defBoardPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
        defBoardPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel((r + 1) + " " + (c + 1));
                label.setOpaque(true);
                if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                    label.setBackground(Color.black);
                    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    System.out.println("LABEL IS OCCUPIED");
                } else {
                    label.setBackground(Color.white);
                }
                defBoardPanel.add(label);
            }
        }
        this.add(defBoardPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

    public static class MainFrame extends JFrame {
        public MainFrame() {
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.setSize(500, 500);
        }

        void startGame() {
            GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();
            this.setContentPane(gp);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
                mainFrame.startGame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code sequence replaces the `GamePanel` after it has been added to `MainFrame`

```
public MainFrame() {
   this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   this.setSize(500, 500);

   SetupBoard sb = new SetupBoard(10, this); // invokes startGame 
   this.setContentPane(sb); <----- GamePanel replaced here
}

void startGame(SetupBoard sb) {
   GamePanel gp = new GamePanel(sb);
   this.setContentPane(gp);
   this.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: +1 the call to `setContentPane` in the `MainFrame` constructor will override the call made by `startGame` (if `startGame` is called in the `SetupBoard` constructor). As I was saying _"Most likely the issue is coming from what you are not showing us."_ ;-)

Comment: That call, which is made in the constructor, doesn't get called after `startGame()` is called. startGame() gets called on a MainFrame instance that already exists. Plus, wouldn't this cause the SetupBoard to be displayed again? It's not, the GamePanel is displayed, just not the panel I have added to it.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: `startGame()` is not called in the SetupBoard constructor, its called by a separate method which is called in an `ActionListener` on a button on the SetupBoard.

Comment: @drewmore I can only recommend to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Don't hesitate to take the one I provided to make your issue appear. Without more info, it will be hard to help you more.